# Finding the maximum and minimum

Tags: optimization

[image: the problem]

Can't understand how to find the maximum and minimum with the given definitions (with both x and y).. can someone explain step by step?

Comment: minimize the Lagrange function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization

Answer (score 2):

First of all compute the gradient of $f$:
$$\nabla f=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)=(1+y^2,2xy)$$
and solve $\nabla f=0$: this equation has no solutions. If it had you would need to pick the ones inside the domain you are considering and check their type by looking at the matrix of second derivatives.

Now you have to look at the boundary $x^2+y^2=4$, that you can parametrize taking $x=2\cos t$ and $y=2\sin t$: hence $f$ restricted to the boundary becomes 
$$f=2\cos t(1+4\sin^2 t)$$
$$\frac{df}{dt}=-2\sin t(1+4\sin^2 t)+2\cos t(8\sin t \cos t)=2\sin t(-1-4\sin^2 t+8\cos^2 t)$$
$$=\sin t(-1-4\sin^2 t+8-8\sin^2 t)=\sin t (7-12\sin^2 t)=\frac{1}{2}y(7-3y^2)=0 $$

From the last equation you can get the $y$ of the critical points and from $x^2+y^2=4$ get the $x$. In the end you obtain  6 points: $(\pm2,0)$, $(\pm\sqrt{5/3},\pm\sqrt{7/3})$. To check if they are maxima or minima you have just to look at the sign of the second derivative (in $t$) of $f$ restricted to the boundary.

[image]

Comment: What software do you use for plotting?

Comment: I used Mathematica

Comment: Which values are the maximum/minimum explicitly?

Comment: The absolute maximum is attained at the points $(\sqrt{5/3},\pm\sqrt{7/3})$ and is $$\frac{10}{3}\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}$$ the minimum is attained at the points $(-\sqrt{5/3},\pm\sqrt{7/3})$ and is $$-\frac{10}{3}\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}$$

Comment: Is there anyway to solve this one with a Lagrange method? Because sin and cos is not necessary in our course - we must know how to solve it without sin/cos/tan. Thankyou for the fast answer Dario!